# В WooCommerce не выводится сохранение способа оплаты

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

При оформлении заказа на странице /checkout в блоке выбора оплаты по идее должен быть checkbox в стиле "Сохранить выбранный способ оплаты". В админке такой настройки не нашел. В прошлых версиях WooCommerce по идее такая настройка была, возможно, она перекочевала в другое место в админке.

Использовал для тестов стандартную тему Storefront, как что c кодом темы проблем нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего сохранение способа оплаты может не выводиться.

Заранее благодарен :)

[image: в этом блоке выбора способа оплаты]

Comment: Такой настройки нет и я не помню, чтобы она была

Comment: а при каких условиях выводиться сохранение способа оплаты?

Comment: Ни при каких, насколько мне известно. Нет такого вообще, в принципе.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что опция сохранения способа оплаты есть только в некоторых плагинах оплаты, в основном в официальных от разработчиков WooCommerce